# How to backup a running linux distro to .img or .iso from within that running distro

Tags: linux, rsync, manjaro

I'm using arch based distro [Manjaro Linux](https://manjaro.org/). The full filesystem is about 6 GB. I want to back it up to an img or an iso.

So far I discovered is

1. Clonezilla. But so far I discovered, clonezilla can't back up from running system.
2. dd - dd copies from block to block. I don't want all of my 250 GB to be backed up. I just want to back up the used 6 GB.
3. I tried [this syncFilesystemToImage.sh git snippet](https://gist.github.com/geoffreyanderson/1004950)

   ```
   # source - https://gist.github.com/geoffreyanderson/1004950

   imageFile=${1:-"awsImage-$(date +%m%d%y-%H%M).img"}
   imageMountPoint=${2:-'/mnt/image'}

   echo "Creating empty 10GB image in ${imageFile}"
   # Create an empty 10GB image file
   dd if=/dev/zero of=${imageFile} bs=1M count=10240

   echo "Creating filesystem in ${imageFile}"
   # Create a filesystem on the image file
   /sbin/mke2fs -F -j ${imageFile}

   echo "Mounting ${imageFile} loopback at ${imageMountPoint}"
   # Create the directories needed for imaging
   mkdir -p ${imageMountPoint}
   mount -o loop ${imageFile} ${imageMountPoint}

   echo "Beginning rsync..."
   rsync --stats -av --exclude=/root/.bash_history --exclude=/home/*/.bash_history --exclude=/etc/ssh/ssh_host_* --exclude=/etc/ssh/moduli --exclude=/etc/udev/rules.d/*persistent-net.rules --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/dev/* / ${imageMountPoint}


   echo "rsync finished. Flushing copied log data..."
   #clear out any remaining log data
   cd ${imageMountPoint}/var/log
   for i in `ls ./**/*`; do
     echo $i && echo -n> $i
   done

   # Create base devices (console, null, zero) under the completed image
   for i in console null zero ; do MAKEDEV -d ${imageMountPoint}/dev -x $i ; done

   # get out of the image mount point so we can successfully unmount
   cd /

   # Sync changes and unmount the image
   sync
   umount ${imageMountPoint}
   rmdir ${imageMountPoint}
   ```

   But this script fails at `rsync`. It says 10 GB is not enough. I don't know why 10 GB is not enough for backing up 6 GB. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Theres a option [systemback](https://launchpad.net/systemback) for ubuntu to solve such problem. Is there any solution for arch based distros ?